# Why replace the masked token with random token in bert?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, transformer-model

Masking in Bert is:

- Take 15% of all the tokens in the sequence. These are to be used in computing the MLM loss
- 80% of the time retain the mask
- 10% of the time replace the mask with the original token
- 10% of the time replace the mask with a random token

I understand why masking is needed. I also understand why the masking is replaced back to the original token. This is because otherwise, the model learns to completely ignore the word itself in deriving its contextual embeddings in the downstream tasks.

What is the need to replace the mask with a random word 10% of the time?

Answer (score 1):

The practice of occasionally replacing the masked token with a random word during BERT's training process serves some crucial purposes, including:

- **Preventing overfitting on the Mask token:** If the model is only trained to predict the original word when it is a masked, it might
  completely rely on the presence of this specific mask token to make
  further predictions. By occasionally replacing the masked token with
  a random word, the model is somehow *forced* to rely more on the
  context provided by the other words, rather than just focusing on
  prediction of the masked token itself.
- **Robustness to noise:** This random replacement enhances the model's robustness to noise, simulating real-world scenarios where
  input data may be imperfect or contain errors.
- **Learning dynamics**: By having a mix of keeping the mask, replacing it with the original token, or a random token, BERT is trained under a variety of conditions. This balance ensures that the model is not overly biased towards any particular type of input manipulation, leading to a more generalized understanding of language.

Comment: aahh.. the second bullet makes a lot of sense. By keeping both the original token and the random noise the encoder learns to decide whether or not the current word is useful in its own embedding. It is like data correction on the fly. "I do not think that is how it is apple" - I know immediately that the word is mostly "done" and the model learns precisely this behavior - that apple does not belong there and it does not use it in deciding the embedding of this token. Genius